# building jstree menu based on xml

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am trying to build the jstree menue based on xml file. My code is this:

```
$("#div").jstree({  
         "xml_data" : {  
             "ajax" : {

             //"url": "jstree.xml" 
                 "url": "http://192.168.101.1/xml/jstree.xml"    
                 },  
             "xsl" : "nest"
               },        
         "plugins" : ["themes", "xml_data", "ui","types"]
```

When the file is local as stated above followed by //, it works. If I tried to access the xml file via http call, it does not work. Any ideas? I really like to call the xml file via http since the file will be updating all the time.

Comment: Did you debug the ajax call with firebug? Did you check access.log of the server? Can you provide working jsfiddle? (this usually helps and you solve it by yourself :-)

Comment: @Radek, I cannot use jsfiddle at work. do you think my syntax is accurate? Again, I can manually access that xml file when I enter it in the url.

Comment: Use firebug and see how the ajax call works. If it returns something. If it finishes. Try to use your xml data without ajax. See if you xml syntax is correct.

Comment: @Radek, dont have firebug, I just check the xml file it is in correct format. When I do "url": "jstree.xml", where the xml file is local, it works. How do you disable ajax?

Comment: @Radek, it is definetly not the xml file. I just tried with a text xml file retrieved from jstree site. Behaving the same.

Comment: What is the url you use to access your jsTree page/application?

Comment: my question is this, is it possible to do this in jstree: "url": "http:/whatever/a.xml", I have not seen any documentation that supports this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that `http://192.168.101.1/xml/jstree.xml` actually returns the xml data.  Also, according to the [Xml data plugin](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/xml_data), the `url` parameter argument needs to be in quotes:

```
$("#div").jstree({  
         "xml_data" : {  
             "ajax" : {

             //"url": "jstree.xml" 
                 "url": "http://192.168.101.1/xml/jstree.xml"      
                 },  
             "xsl" : "nest"
               },        
         "plugins" : ["themes", "xml_data", "ui","types"]
```

Comment: I can open the xml file from the my dev environment. It is actually in double quotes and when I run, it keeps saying loading. So, it is not finding the xml file. I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: it was not the quotes and it is not the xml file. I just check the xml file is valid. It works when I have the xml file local to my dev environment. when I do "url": "jstree.xml", it works.