# Unable to load an XML file via HTTP in jsTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am asking this question again. I have this piece of code that loads a jsTree based on an XML file:

```
$("#div").jstree({
    "xml_data" : {
        "ajax" : {
            "url": "http://192.168.101.1/xml/jstree.xml"
        },
        "xsl" : "nest"
    },
    "plugins" : ["themes", "xml_data", "ui","types"]
```

When the file is on the same server as my script, it works. My tree loads.

```
"url": "jstree.xml"
```

But when I do this:

```
"url": "http://192.168.101.1/xml/jstree.xml"
```

I keep getting that infinite loading on the page. It is the same XML file and I can defitely access that XML manually when entered into my browser.

Anybody has seen this issue with jsTree? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Duplicate posts are discouraged: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957646/building-jstree-menu-based-on-xml Please provide a fiddle on the previous post.

Comment: @MMeah, I cannot use jsfiddle from work. My question is very simple. Is it possible to do url: "http//data.xml" file within jstree plugin. I dont see any reference to it. I tried to do it and not working.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Javascript error? Where is your xml lying when not on the server? Could it be a crossdomain issue?

Comment: @mahatmanich looks like a cross domain issue, I dont know how to get around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the issue by creating an server side script and calling the script file within my jquery. It works well.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it's a cross domain restriction.  You can't get XML cross domain.  So work around is either a server side proxy solution for example

```
<?php readfile($_GET['url']) ?>
```

[more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550839/need-help-with-getting-cross-domain-xml-with-javascript)

Or use [yahoo pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) to convert your remote xml data into jsonp.  Looking at the jstree docs it seems you can pass a jquery ajax object which hopefully could be one that's setup to do jsonp.    Or manually get a jsonp response and pass it in to jstree as a json object.